# uwsgi does not reload after changing django settings

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have set up uwsgi to serve django behind nginx. Then I change the database in django settings but uwsgi still shows the site with old database.

I also tried [this suggestion](https://serverfault.com/a/411363/249519)  and added

```
touch-reload = /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/django.ini
```

to the ini file. But after restarting uwsgi and touching `django.ini` it still serves the old site. I tried to deactivate and reactivate virtualenv, no chance either. So really got confused and appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 16):

From uWSGI docs about [touch-reload](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#touch-reload):
reload uWSGI if the specified file is modified/touched
So if you want to reload on changes in settings.py, you should do:

```
touch-reload = /path/to/your/django-project/settings.py
```

Directive you've used before reloads uWSGI on any changes in uWSGI ini file.

FYI, of you need to restart uWSGI on changes in codebase also, you can use py-autoreload directive: 
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#py-autoreload
So you should have something like this in your uwsgi.ini

```
py-autoreload = 1
```

Note, these options aren't recommended for production.
Good luck!

Comment: Setting  `UWSGI_PY_AUTORELOAD: "1"` In my environment made it reload my code.  Thank you very much this is an absolute livesaver for development.

Answer (score 6):

This is my uWSGI's configure file

```
wsgi-file = /home/www-data/djcode/metCCS/metCCS/nginx/wsgi.py
processer = 4
threads = 2
stats = 127.0.0.1:6000
enable-threads = true
master = true
harakiri = 30
socket = /usr/share/nginx/html/ng-sock/metCCS.sock
chmod-socket = 775
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
touch-reload = /home/www-data/djcode/metCCS/metCCS/settings.py
```

then, `touch /home/www-data/djcode/metCCS/metCCS/settings.py` works fine.

Comment: You rock dude mate!

Answer (score 2):

The reason Belter's answer fixed your problem is that uWSGI can only gracefully restart when running with the master process mode.
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#reloading-the-server

I just had to add `master=true` to my ini file to make the `touch-reload` argument work.