# Where to add uswgi.reload() function in django app to restart the server whenever code changes occur

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have a code snippet which i got from web to restart the uWsgi + Django stack, whenever code changes occur. But How to register and where to add this snippet  or how to implement this in django.

```
import uwsgi
from uwsgidecorators import timer
from django.utils import autoreload

@timer(3)
def change_code_gracefull_reload(sig):
    if autoreload.code_changed():
        uwsgi.reload()
```

I am new to python and Django, so please forgive me if anything is wrong.

Comment: There is an [answer on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/411362/how-do-i-make-uwsgi-restart-when-a-python-script-is-modified) Plus this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813166/uwsgi-does-not-reload-after-changing-django-settings) question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but this code snippet can be placed in `wsgi.py`.